# How to display category post on custom template in Magento Fishpig?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, fishpig

I'm having two post categories in my project, and both categories are using different views. I'm using fishpig plugin to add and categorize post, But both the category posts are using the same **view.phtml** template for displaying the post.

```
<wordpress_post_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="wordpress/post_view" name="wp.post.view" template="wordpress/post/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="post.content.before" as="before_post_content" />
            <block type="core/text_list" name="post.content.after" as="after_post_content">
                <block type="wordpress/post_meta" name="wp.post.view.meta" as="meta" after="-" template="wordpress/post/meta.phtml">
                    <action method="setDisplayPreviousNextLinks"><display>1</display></action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="wordpress/post_view_comment_wrapper" name="wp.post.view.comments" as="comments" template="wordpress/post/view/comment/wrapper.phtml">
                <block type="wordpress/post_view_comments" name="wp.post.view.comments.list" as="comment_list" template="wordpress/post/view/comments.phtml" />
                <block type="wordpress/post_view_comment_pager" name="wp.post.view.comments.pager" as="pager"/>
                <block type="wordpress/post_view_comment_form" name="wp.post.view.comments.form" as="form" template="wordpress/post/view/comment/form.phtml">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="wp.post.view.comments.form.before_end" as="before_form_end" />
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    </wordpress_post_view>
```

Is there any way to split up the post view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use 2 different post types rather than splitting the posts by category. This would allow you to have a separate template for each post type quite easily.

If you want to use categories, you would need to customise the view.phtml and add a check to see what category the current post is in and then display the appropriate content.

Comment: Thanks Ben, for splitting the post by category should I use Post Types & Taxonomies Extension?

Comment: If you want to use categories, you would need to call $post->getTermCollection('category') and loop through the categories to determine which category the post is in. To split by Post Types you would need the Post Types add-on extension.

Comment: While I'm trying to use getTermCollection('category')  it's showing **Call to a member function getTermCollection() on a non-object** can you please share me the syntax??

Comment: The syntax is correct but you need to ensure that $post is set tin the template.

Comment: `<?php $post = $this->getPost()->getTermCollection('category');?>
<?php if ($post): ?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('wordpress') ?>`   Am i doing right?

Comment: `$post = Mage::getModel('wordpress/term')->load($categoryId);` by using this code I'm getting categoryId, slug, name etc.